# jQuery Ajax Request abort() still queues previous requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, request, abort

I've encountered a strange behaviour when I try to abort previous jQuery AJAX requests.

Scenario:

- A single Button with an AJAX-Call that gets a good amount of data. A normal request (1 click) needs ~1.75s.

Screenshot: [Network Monitor: Single Request (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNx3a.png)

Of course I want to prevent multiple clicks, so I have a function that aborts the previous requests. In the next example I did 7 fast clicks in a row.

In the Network Monitor I can see that the previous requests gets directly canceled as soon as I do the next request. Works as expected? Seems so, but actually not.

Because the very last ACTIVE request needs now **20 seconds to complete, instead of ~1.75s**?

See screenshot: [Multiple Requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IeIK.png)

Where is the mistake? Thank you in advance.

The JS code:

```
var theRequest;
function registerAjaxInterceptor(linkElementSelector, outputTime) {
    $('body').on('click', linkElementSelector, function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $linkElement = $(this);
        var uri = $linkElement.attr('href');

        theRequest = $.ajax(
            uri,
            {
                'type': 'post',
                'beforeSend': function()    {
                    if(theRequest != null) {
                        theRequest.abort();
                    }
                },
            }
        ).done(function (result) {

        });
    });

}

registerAjaxInterceptor('.ajax-link', false);
```

Comment: I do believe the problem is that you are only cancelling the client side of the ajax call. Once the url of the ajax call is requested, the server will begin its work and send back the data when it is done. When you cancel the client side, the server response is ignored, but just cause you cancel the client side of the request does not mean the server is not still busy processing all previous requests. The server does not know that you don't need it to work anymore.